# Unusual management style?: Using team meetings to critically evaluate team members' performance

Tags: team-management

I recently started my first industry job as a member of a small team of data scientists at a large corporation. In daily team meetings, each team member sets a goal for the day, and if they did not achieve their goal from their previous day then the manager asks followup questions about what went wrong and sometimes offers criticism of this team member's performance -- all in the presence of the other team members. For instance, *they might say to a team member that they are being unfair to the team by not making enough progress*. My question is this: **How unusual is this style of management for this type of position?**

I understand it may be difficult to find data which would be needed to give a quantitative answer to the question. But possibly there could exist references within the business or management literature which could at least provide evidence as to whether this is or is not a commonly accepted form of management. Insights from personal experience could also help to address the question.

*Edit*: I am asking this question because I am considering quitting the job on account of the fact that I find this management style to be unpleasant and ineffective. It comes across to me as heavy-handed, in setting up a situation where the manager seems to be shaming team members in front of their peers, based on their performance. I would have thought that performance concerns about individual employees would be appropriately addressed on a one-on-one basis. But in weighing the option of quitting, I would like to understand how likely it is that I may encounter a similar situation with a future employer. I am also preparing to have a discussion with my manager about my concerns, and being informed about this beforehand could be useful.

Comment: Not completely sure this is a project management question; sounds like a workplace question.

Comment: Seconded. "How to deal with an offensive management practice?" is a better workplace question than "Is this management practice common?" as a PM one.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I tried to find the closest Stack Exchange I could for the topic and wasn't aware of "The Workplace" one. @Sarov, your answer was very helpful and much appreciated, as I hadn't heard of daily Scrum before. (I would +1 but it won't let me because of insufficient reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the edit to your question and for adding more context .

This appears to be a case of poor management style and not the best way to provide critical feedback if it is leading to you experiencing "public shaming" and "high handiness"

If you are thinking about quitting your job purely due to this, I would advise you to be mindful of these two things -

1. There is absolutely no guarantee that you would not come across an individual with such a management style in the next company .
2. A lot of this time this kind of management style does not get challenged enough (especially by relatively less experienced folks) who tend to either accept the status quo or move on without challenging it.

Good on you for planning to raise it with you manager but before you challenge it ensure that ...

1. You go into that discussion having ruled out that this is not a case of right intentions but poor execution by that Manager (e.g maybe the concerned manager wants to create a culture where anyone can challenge anyone in the Team and open accountability but the way the frame their questions or their questioning technique is such that it comes across to you as toxic or abrasive to you personally )
2. Make sure you start by articulating(to your Manager)  the impact that this kind of leadership style is having on you  (in terms of you thinking about quitting) rather than purely expressing your concerns about that Manager's behavior.  Personally I have framed my concerns in similar situations as ... "when Person X does  ..it makes me feel  instead of  " . This helps to create empathy towards your situation rather than just coming across as complaining about someone's behavior.

Hope it goes well for you

Comment: Thank you for the advice; it was very helpful! The meeting went well, and I believe the situation has been completely resolved. Such a relief! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is not particularly unusual at all. It sounds very similar to the daily Scrum or daily Standup in Scrum. A main difference being that the daily Scrum is intended to be by and for the Team, rather than the Team reporting to management.

I assume that your purpose for asking this question is because you are uncertain of the validity or purpose of this management style. In which case, my suggestion would be to ask management itself why it does this. What the purpose is for which it runs this meeting, and what it gets out of it.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to explain my purpose for asking, and to clarify that my concern focuses on the manager using the meeting as an opportunity to criticize team members' performance, e.g. to tell a team member that he or she is being unfair to the team by not making enough progress. Would you still say that it is not unusual for a team meeting to include this sort of element?